# In ASP.Net, I sometimes get the following error - Viewstate verification failed. Reason: The viewstate supplied failed integrity check

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, iis-7, viewstate

Background:  I developed a web app in ASP.Net 3.5 in C#.  It runs great but now a few users have reported that they recieve an error sometimes.  I have tried to duplicate the error but it has been hard.  One time though when I let the app sit I came back later and tried to move it along and it errored out.  I would think that has something to do with the timeout but I am using the view state.

Any ideas?  When I look at the eventLog I do see the following error entry.

Thank You for your help and ideas!

John

---

My event log has the following errors:

Event code: 4005

Event message: Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied has expired.

Event time: 14/03/2008 13:19:26

Event time (UTC): 14/03/2008 13:19:26

Event ID: d9f0333c2eed46e0b0207da69d2ea70e

Event sequence: 154

Event occurrence: 5

Event detail code: 50202

---

Event code: 3005

Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.

Event time: 3/12/2009 7:49:59 AM

Event time (UTC): 3/12/2009 11:49:59 AM

Event ID: 590ac0f6ad734d988e9e02f0fb7800eb

Event sequence: 52

Event occurrence: 1

Event detail code: 0

Application information:

```
Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/32/ROOT-1-128813294498061103 

Trust level: Full 

Application Virtual Path: / 

Application Path: C:\Home\LocalUser\ucpga\Web\ 

Machine name: 169349-WEB2
```

Process information:

```
Process ID: 6912 

Process name: w3wp.exe 

Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
```

---

Here is the latest error:

Event code: 4009 
Event message: Viewstate verification failed. Reason: The viewstate supplied failed integrity check. 
Event time: 3/15/2009 10:26:27 PM 
Event time (UTC): 3/16/2009 2:26:27 AM 
Event ID: 3b5be134005e49c3b40400bcaa5cb48d 
Event sequence: 56 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 50203

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/32/ROOT-1-128816433841748972 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\Home\LocalUser\ucpga\Web\ 
    Machine name: 169349-WEB2

Process information: 
    Process ID: 8892 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Request information: 
    Request URL: https://hr.ucpga.org:443/application.aspx 
    Request path: /application.aspx 
    User host address: 74.160.64.222 
    User:
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:
    Thread account name: 169349-WEB2\ucpga

ViewStateException information: 
    Exception message: Invalid viewstate. 
    Client IP: 74.160.64.222 
    Port: 1251 
    User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; GTB5; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; InfoPath.1)

Comment: Also the site is running on IIS7

Comment: John instead of adding answer whith additional info you should edit and update your question. This is the standard on stackoverflow...makes it easy to find the question / answer latter on...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This issue can often be caused by having auto-generated `<machineKey />` keys in your server's `machine.config` file. Each time your application starts afresh it will generate new keys. This invalidates any existing encrypted viewstate or forms authentication tickets.

Try setting the `<machineKey />` `validationKey` and `decryptionKey` to fixed values. See the following link for more information:

> [How To: Configure MachineKey in ASP.NET 2.0 (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I strongly doubt if this problem has anything to do with Viewstate. It has more to do with Session state and Authentication cookies.

Is your application running on a Web farm/garden ? If so, you should take a look at [this article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/omar/archive/2006/08/20/108307.aspx).

If not, this error can commonly occur if your FormsAuthenticationTicket timeout is less than the Session Timeout. What happens is that the Auth ticket expires sooner than the user's session and the next request is unable to be authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an authentication issue. You probally have a timeout set on the authentication ticket which is expiring. If you use a sliding timeout then every time you hit the server the ticket will be renewed. If you don't your tickets will expire and you'll need to handle this case.

---

#### Edit:

You can check out this [support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555353) article to see if it applies to you.

Also you can check out this [view state viewer](http://alt.pluralsight.com/tools.aspx) might help you determine if the view state is invalid.

Here's another good [post from a Microsoft Escalation Engineer](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2007/06/11/a-case-of-invalid-viewstate.aspx)

Comment: There is no authentication for the application either.  Should I still set the form authentication tag?

Comment: hmmm if you have no authentication then I don't man...that error is very specific. Your positive your not using Forms Authentication

Answer (score 1):

I also had this error....

If you look at the error, its likely your encrypted URL query string. What happens is the webresource.axd generated URL string has identities that were encrypted using the machinekey setting. These expire and if you have a page where you sit then try and submit using the encrypted string, the Event ID 1316 or 4009 is fired. You camn probably capture this exception in the Application_Error event and check whether the CryptographicException was fired.