# ASP.NET 4.0 ViewState Invalid Error Just Won't Go

Tags: asp.net, webforms, viewstate

I have HealthMonitoring on for my website. 90% of my pages are accessed in the format

http://www.itsmywebsite.com/showproduct.aspx?id=somenumber
I was checking the WebEvents_events tables and saw that my table is full of this error

```
0002609ad8vdf45f8daffc7de8716e32    2013-11-25 17:01:18.153 2013-11-25 11:01:18.153 System.Web.Management.WebViewStateFailureAuditEvent 9877    1455    4009    50204   Viewstate verification failed. Reason: Viewstate was invalid.   C:\HostingSpaces\parthak\itsmywebsite.com\wwwroot\  /   C15472-132183   http://www.itsmywebsite.com/showproduct.aspx    NULL    Event code: 4009
    Event message: Viewstate verification failed. Reason: Viewstate was invalid.
    Event time: 11/25/2013 11:01:18 AM
    Event time (UTC): 11/25/2013 5:01:18 PM
    Event ID: 0002609ad8vdf45f8daffc7de8716e32
    Event sequence: 9877
    Event occurrence: 1455
    Event detail code: 50204

    Application information:
        Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/94/ROOT-1-1302342423433586
        Trust level: Full
        Application Virtual Path: /
        Application Path: C:\HostingSpaces\parthak\itsmywebsite.com\wwwroot\
        Machine name: C15472-132183

    Process information:
        Process ID: 28796
        Process name: w3wp.exe
        Account name: C15472-132183\itsmywebsitecom_web

    Request information:
        Request URL: http://www.itsmywebsite.com/showproduct.aspx
        Request path: /showproduct.aspx
        User host address: 186.xx.xxx.xx
        User: 
        Is authenticated: False
        Authentication Type: 
        Thread account name: C15472-132183\itsmywebsitecom_web

    ViewStateException information:
        Exception message: Invalid viewstate. 
        Client IP: 186.xx.xxx.xx
        Port: 29991
        Referer: 
        Path: /showproduct.aspx
        User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Synapse)
```

There were a few SO threads that suggested that setting EnableViewStateMac to false solves the issue. But in my case it doesn't.

What else do I do or look?

Comment: Have you tried setting the machineKey value in your web.config? The answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650353/in-asp-net-i-sometimes-get-the-following-error-viewstate-verification-failed?rq=1 has more info.

Comment: yes I have already done that. No effect.

Comment: What version of .net are you using? Are you using a CMS? I'm guessing you are using a hosting service. This could be due to caching on load balancers.